# Order Comments ignoring ahref links in Email Notification

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

Referring to the topic on this question, ahref links sent out from the order comments in Sales > Order are not showing on Email Notifications as shown on the screenshot below.

**Order Comments with ahref links**
[image]

**Email received but not showing ahref links** 
[image]

I've check on the Email templates using FTP app > locale > en_US > template > email > sales > order_update.html , I can't configure anything to `{{var comment}}`. Can we do anything to enable HTML for `{{var comment}}`?

```
 <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">You can check the status of your order by <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">logging into your account</a>.</p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">{{var comment}}</p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
                        If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us at
                        <a href="mailto:{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}</a>
                        or by phone at {{config path='general/store_information/phone'}}.
                    </p>
```

Comment: Please check submit button method in that check how they are follow the structure

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually meant, but isn't submit buttons belong to magento core files? We can't actually do anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Magento does not allow html tags in the order comments.
The "problem" is not in the e-mail. It's in the controller that handles the comments.
Take a look in `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController::addCommentAction`.
Somewhere in there there is this line:

```
$comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));
```

So if you want tags in comments you need to rewrite the method I mentioned above.

if you plan to show that comment in frontend also, you might need to change the template:
`app/design/frotnend/{package}/{theme}/template/sales/order/view.phtml` and replace:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_historyItem->getComment()) ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $_historyItem->getComment() ?>
```

Comment: Which means I just remove the trim(strip_tags from the code?

Comment: @DroidBeginner. Basically yes, but don't edit the core code. rewrite the methods properly. [See here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) how you can override a controller.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer. Will open  a new question if I need help for rewrites on controllers. Thanks.

Comment: I do want to note that removing `escapeHtml()` could be dangerous. This way you could end up having unwanted HTML code or even JavaScripts injected in your website.

Comment: `echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b', 'br', 'strong', 'i', 'u', 'a'))` is there a way to include the href property in the allowed tags list?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.1.1 links will actually work for all order mails except the order overview itself.

The tip to modify `view.phtml` was however very helpful, for comments to display correctly on Invoice and Creditmemo view, you will also have to edit `sales/order/comments.phtml`:

Change

```
<dd><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_commentItem->getComment()) ?></dd>
```

to

```
<dd><?php echo $_commentItem->getComment() ?></dd>
```

I am still trying to figure out, how to display Shipment comments in the frontend. According to the code, this should be possible, I see however no option in the backend to display a comment on the frontend...